# Call Future after OnChanged function executes in Flutter

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart

I want to get the Future executed right after the onChanged function does, because I need to first change the `selectedPetValueType` before calling the api for the new petRaces found by the petType. Example:

If I've chosen to look for `petType = dog`, but before that I selected `petType = cat` it will display cat races instead of dogs, and if once again I change it to cats, it will display dogs, because it has stored the last value before the `onChange` function.

Code here:

```
Widget obtainPetsTypeDropdownButton() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: ApiPets.retreivePetRaces(selectedValuePetType.index),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return Container(
            width: 100.0,
            child: DropdownButton<PetType>(
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                dropdownColor: Colors.blue[800],
                value: selectedValuePetType,
                onChanged: (PetType newValue) {
                  selectedValuePetType = newValue;
                  isRaceVisible = selectedValuePetType != PetType.Otro;
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                    loadedRaces = snapshot.data;
                    selectedValuePetRace = loadedRaces.first.petRaceId;
                    setState(() {});
                  }
                },
                items: PetType.values.map((PetType classType) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<PetType>(
                      value: classType, child: Text(classType.name));
                }).toList()));
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: setState should call the build method again which will rebuild your widget tree with the new value

Comment: why inside setState? @PeterHaddad

Comment: What do you mean inside? You are calling here `setState(() {});` isnt this rebuild your widget tree with the new value that you assigned here `selectedValuePetType = newValue;`?

Comment: yes, you're true, but it's still not working, idk why @PeterHaddad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, making the onChanged function asynchronous was the way to fix it.

```
onChanged: (PetType newValue) async {
              selectedValuePetType = newValue;
              isRaceVisible = selectedValuePetType != PetType.Otro;
              await updatePetRaces(selectedValuePetType.index);
              setState(() {});
            },
```